# Why do zero gravity flights not stall?

Tags: stall, aircraft-physics

Airbus' (A300 / A310) are being used by French companies (i.e. [Novespace](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/zero-g-flying-means-high-stress-for-an-old-a310-410416/)) that offer zero G flights.

Now the airbus seems to risk a stall at a **40** degree angle of attack (i.e.[Air France 447](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_447)).

In a zero g flight, they climb at **45** degrees and then nose dive at the same angle.

Why does the climb not stall the aircraft?

Comment: The angle of climb is not the same as the angle of attack.

Comment: The above comment is correct, please don't confuse Angle of Attack with climb angle (gradient).

Comment: @RonBeyer What is the difference please?

Comment: See: [Can the pitch be very different from the angle of attack?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/can-the-pitch-be-very-different-from-the-angle-of-attack).

Comment: Angle of attack: Angle between relative air flow and aircraft longitudinal axis (roughly: Angle between flight path and aircraft nose in side view. „Does it point where it goes?“). // Pitch angle: Angle between level plane and aircraft longitudinal axis (Angle between nose and horizon in side view). // The two are only the same in zero wind level flight.

Comment: @CptReynolds Ok thanks. Should I delete the question?

Comment: You’re welcome! Not sure re. deleting - it may help others with the same question? For an admin to decide!

Comment: @Cloud You are asking two questions and both have been answered. However, you don't need to delete it. Let it get closed.

Comment: I don't think the proposed duplicate is the same question at all. That question is about stalling in the zero-g phase of flight, while this question is about stalling in the climb.

Comment: The pitch angle is not the angle of attack, here's a diagram   https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-361a07f4547f260fd936b17aafd7b93b-c

Answer (score 3):

The aero-dynamics of a flight in reduced gravity are different than a flight operating in normal conditions. When an aircraft is experiencing zero gravity, it does not stall because the wings are not generating any lift, because the aircraft is in a state of weightlessness.

In the paper for the requirements for zero gravity flights, it is [mentioned (PDF)](https://spacemedicineassociation.org/download/history/history_files_1958/29060428-1.pdf):

> ... zero G flights stalling conditions are different as compared to
>   conventional flight maneuvers, because the plane is weightless and is,
>   therefore, in no need of aerodynamical support. On the other hand, a
>   minimum speed is required to execute the delicate control through the
>   parabola. For this reason the stalling speed is taken as the minimum
>   aircraft velocity required for effective control.

Comment: It sounds a bit like a sailing craft needs a little "way", as sailors say, to steer, to control.

Comment: But I was referring to the climb, not the ZG phase

Comment: The climb is fine, @Cloud - the airspeed and angle of attack are not likely to cause a stall. The pilot is not trying to hold the nose up and lose speed such that a stall occurs, but instead aims for a parabolic arc.